# Прорисовка примитивов с помощью Graphics, перемещение на С#

Tags: c#, winforms, form, графика, таймер

Отрисовываю enemy через цикл, их количество зависит от количества итераций, каждый новый enemy смещается по 'y' на какое то определенное значение, проблема в следующем, все enemy перемещаются с одной скоростью, не понимаю как можно ее контролировать, и менять у каждого enemy, пробовал прибавлять скорость каждую итерацию, но всё равно они движутся одинаково(отметил на картинке).

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace workLeisan
{
    class Enemy
    {
        int x = 0;
        int _y = 0;
        int enemy_Width = 25;
        int enemy_Height = 25;
        int speedEnemy=10;

        private int amount;

        bool flag = true;

        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 3.0F);
        Random random = new Random();
        int[] _speed = new int[] {1,3,2,5,4};

        Timer timer;

        public void LoadForm()
        {
            timer = new Timer {Interval=24};
          //  timer.Tick += (s,e)=>move_Enemy();
            timer.Enabled = true;
        }


        public float move_Enemy()
        {
           // speedEnemy = _speed[n];
            if (flag)
            {
                x += speedEnemy;
                if (x >= 370) flag = false;
            }
            if (!flag)
            {
                x -= speedEnemy;
                if (x <= 0) flag = true;
            }
            return (float)x;
        }

        public void draw_Enemy(Graphics canvas)
        {
            for (int i = 0, cdvig = 0; i < 3; i++, cdvig += 50)
            {
                int speed = random.Next(1,5);
                canvas.DrawEllipse(pen, x, cdvig, 30, 30);
            }

        }
    }
}



using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace workLeisan
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {

        private int x;
        private int y;
        private int _y=10;
        int amount;
        Pen pen = new Pen(Color.Black, 5.0F);

        Enemy enemy1 = new Enemy();
        Timer _timer;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            x = 280;
            y = 400;


        }

        private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            enemy1.LoadForm();
        }

        private void Form1_Paint(object sender, PaintEventArgs e)
        {
            Graphics canvas = e.Graphics;

            enemy1.draw_Enemy(canvas);
            e.Graphics.FillRectangle(Brushes.Blue, x, y, 20, 20);

        }


        private void Timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
         enemy1.move_Enemy();
         Invalidate();
        }


        private void control_Hero(object sender, KeyEventArgs e)
        {
            if (y > 0 && e.KeyData == Keys.Up)
            {
                y -= 10;
            }
            if (y < 430 && e.KeyData == Keys.Down)
            {
                y += 10;
            }
            if (x > 0 && e.KeyData == Keys.Left)
            {
                x -= 10;
            }
            if (x < 330 && e.KeyData == Keys.Right)
            {
                x += 10;
            }
        }

    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: И правильно, вы же не меняете speedEnemy с начального значения 10, вот он и передвигается с такой скоростью

Comment: Я пробовал менять, ничего не изменяется

Comment: Конечно, ведь это значение начально для всех экземпляров этого класса. Принимайте скорость в конструкторе  класса

Comment: А нельзя использовать один экземпляр класса?просто надо разное количество задавать их, и для этого я его в цикле рисую, т.е. один экземпляр я рисую несколько раз

Comment: Для этого существует прекрасный шаблон легковес(приспособленец).